# Repmat a matrix rows as per another matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, membership

I have 2 matrices with the `same IDs`.  `mat1` has multiple rows per ID while `mat2` has `ONLY 1` row per ID.  Matrices are pre-sorted.

```
% COL1 -> ID
mat1 = [ 20 2008 0.11 ; 20 2010 0.22  ; 30 2001 0.99 ; 40 2011 0.11 ; 40 2011 0.22 ; 40 2012 0.11 ] ; 
mat2 = [ 20 0.88 ; 30 0.11 ; 40 0.99 ] ;
```

mat2 IDs need to be repeated as per their corresponding number of rows in mat1.

```
mat2 = [ 20 0.88 ; 20 0.88 ; 30 0.11 ; 40 0.99 ; 40 0.99 ; 40 0.99 ] ;
```

Can you suggest an answer?  On my own, I thought of using `accmarray` etc to get row count per ID and then may be repmat mat2.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[b,m,n] = unique(mat1(:,1));
mat3 = mat2(n,:)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks!  straightforward... why did i even think about accumarray!